# Classes include and creation in C++

Tags: c++, class, include

What is the difference between

> Writing **class{ };** in before the **main();** and using it

and

> **Add class** which create class.h file and class.cpp file beside the source.cpp file

?

Is it really different or the same?!

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"**create class**"_??

Comment: Please provide examples. I don't know such directive as **create class** in C++.

Comment: You don't include classes. You include files.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i meant add class which creates 2 more file one with .h and other with .cpp extension

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem I don't know this either. Are you talking about a particular IDEs command? Then I still get about what difference you are talking.

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to a feature of some IDE (computer program), and one that is slightly mangling the terminology and conventions of C++ itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ an image for adding class and the other is just making class in the source.cpp

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem Looks like Visual Studio. I still don't get your question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> #include <class>
> ```

This is a C++ directive that you write in your C++ code. It tells C++ that the line should be replaced with the contents of the file `class` during compilation.

Note that we include *files*, not *classes*, although some IDEs abstract away that distinction by encouraging you to write exactly one class per file. This assumes Object-Oriented Programming, which you may not be using. Prefer examples like `#include <file>` to be more inclusive and "correct".

> "Add class" which create class.h file and class.cpp file beside the source.cpp file

Can only guess at this, really, but this sounds like a command in your IDE. As described, it conveniently creates source files for you with a given name, ready for writing code in... and ready for being `#include`d where appropriate.

The two are entirely unrelated.

Comment: so can i just use class {}; in the same file as main function or i have to add class and create the file .h and .cpp???

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem: Put your class definitions wherever you like. Your IDE is just giving you handy shortcuts to create files. Unfortunately, the names it gives to these features are misleading. "Add file that I can put class-related things into if I wish..." might be a better name for the option.